# Docker Toolbox SSH Login

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-toolbox

I update my boot2docker to DockerToolbox.

Now I try to connect to my database with Sequal Pro (MySQL Client) but my ssh Login to my VM fails with the following username and password:

IP: **192.168.99.100**

User: **docker**

Password: **tcuser**

How can I find the right username and password for ssh login in DockerToolbox?

[image]

When I try to connect with terminal I see following warning

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deleting the line with ip 192.168.99.100 from known_hosts file it works!